# Firebase + BigQuery - Uniquely Identifying Devices

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, looker-studio

Recently started exploring the Firebase data via the Data Studio Firebase connector. I'm doing some custom reports based on the user_engagement event to compare with data we previously reported on in Flurry.

When looking at some DAU figures they are pretty close but on MAU they tend to get inflated. (Saw this behavior first on the Firebase Events Report Template). Digging into it a little more we do have a pattern where users frequently reinstall the app which generates a new app_instance_id. So as I fallback I'm using the resettable_device_id but then there's the situation advertising tracking is disabled on device resulting in a zeroed value. (Or for a brief period in January nulled out values, not sure if this was client or part of the Firebase link)

Currently thinking something roughly following the logic below, falling back to app_instance_id if the advertising identifier was not set. What approaches would be worth looking into to have a reliable user identifier for metrics reporting? (In future will be calling the setUserID to utilize our own identifier but looking to match up historical data)

```
  IF(user_dim.device_info.resettable_device_id is not null, 
      IF(user_dim.device_info.resettable_device_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id, user_dim.device_info.resettable_device_id),
      user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id
     ) as unique_user_identifier,
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler way to deal with the cases where a resettable_device_id is not available:

```
IF(user_dim.device_info.limited_ad_tracking, user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id, user_dim.device_info.resettable_device_id) as unique_user_identifier
```